# How to build my own ConfirmAjaxButton in Apache Wicket?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, wicket

I need to modify com.googlecode.wicket.jquery.ui.form.button.ConfirmAjaxButton to first check if the form was modified by the user. So I copied the code into

> BlockingCloseButton

But when using it in a form, I get the exception

> Last cause: Failed to find markup file associated. BlockingCloseButton: [BlockingCloseButton [Component id = closeButton]]

How can I solve this? I haven't found a markup file for ConfirmAjaxButton.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the markup file in

> wicket-jquery-ui-7.1.0-javadoc.jar : com/googlecode/wicket/jquery/ui/form/button/ConfirmAjaxButton.html

Thanks to the nice tool **JarExplorer** by Igor Polevoy